# Non-chess usage of "patzer"?

Tags: etymology, slang, origin-unknown, german, yiddish

I've heard the word *patzer* used to describe an incompetent or amateurish chess player. Is it ever used in a non-chess context?

Comment: In English or in Yiddish? Among non-Jews, I am fairly sure it's only used for chess players. I don't know about among Jews who use lots of Yiddish words.

Comment: You can bet that it *will* be used for non-chess contexts, from now on, thanks to this Q&A.

Comment: *Is it ever used in a non-chess context?* **Ever** has a very broad reach.

Comment: It is used *by* chess players to refer to non-chess dufferdom among themselves, but that is about the extent of it from my experience.

Comment: Almost forty years ago it was shown that English *patzer* has no Jewish connection of any kind. The word comes from German *Patzer*. See Gold, David L. 1982. *Etymological Studies of Jewish Interest, Part I* [= *Comments on Etymology*, vol. XI, no. 15]. Pp. 41-42.

Comment: Is this an English word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, *patzer* evidently is (or at least has been) sometimes used in a nonchess context, as we see in this excerpt from Victor Niederhoffer, [*The Education of a Speculator*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9FmIMKJ7FX8C&pg=PA155&dq=%22a+patzer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnx66htf3SAhXqhlQKHW_DAL84ChDoAQg9MAc#v=onepage&q=%22a%20patzer%22&f=false) (1998):

> As I trust has become abundantly clear by now, I have followed all my father's advice as closely as the Greeks followed the Delphic oracle. While I was courting the future Mrs. Niederhoffer, who not only understood my profession but helped to create it as my assistant, I figured I should expose her to the board games as a litmus test. I took her to the  game tables at Washington Square Park, where I had played many games with my father as a boy. I prevailed on Susan to wait while I tried to get a game. Traditionally, veteran checkers players at the park won't play with a stranger because they don't want to waste time on a "**patzer**." I asked a number of players for a game, but they all refused. Finally, someone said, "Junior will play you."

So *patzer* has been used, in essentially the same sense, in both chess **and** checkers. Venturing even farther afield, we find this, in [*ISLA*](https://books.google.com/books?id=8_EnAQAAMAAJ&q=%22a+patzer%22&dq=%22a+patzer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO1uHe2v3SAhVqsFQKHVIGClM4RhDoAQgeMAE), volume 8 (1974) [combined snippets]:

> I spent much of my time on the tennis courts. For those who grudgingly shell out $20 or $30 an hour for indoor courts. in New Yok, St. Croix is a **patzer**'s paradise. There are some fine courts available at several hotels—the Buccaneer, St. Croix-by-the-Sea, the Caribbean ReefClub—and there is a lovely new tennis club high on Mount Royal.

But in the vast majority of instances, the milieu is chess, and most slang and idiom dictionaries focus on that angle. For, example, John Ayto, *Oxford Dictionary of Slang* (1999) has this entry for the term, under the category heading "Chess":

> **patzer** (1959) Applied to a weak player; origin uncertain; compare German *patzen* bungle [Example:] ***Daily Telegraph***: So Fischer after besting off a ferocious attack ...'played like a patzer', said one  American Grandmaster, 'went to sleep on the job' said another. (1972)

And from Harold Wentworth & Stuart Flexner, *Dictionary of American Slang* (1960):

> **patzer** *n.* An inferior chess player. *Although said to be from the Yiddish, there is no Yiddish, German, or Hebrew word or word combination to suggest it. Prob. from "patsy" with the familiar"—er" ending added.*

Robert Chapman, *New Dictionary of American Slang* (1986), however, is less inclined to write off the possible connection to Yiddish:

> **patzer** or **potzer** *n* A mediocre but often enthusiastic chess player {probably fr Yiddish; see *potsky* [defined in the book under an entry for "**potchkie** or **potchky** or **potsky**" as "To putter; tinker; =MESS"]}

The earliest mention of the term that I've been able to find is from the [*American Mercury*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q4TQAAAAMAAJ&q=%22a+potzer%22&dq=%22a+potzer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid-_ni3f3SAhVrslQKHY_6DKo4ChDoAQglMAI), volume 20 (1930) [combined snippets:

> I was then the queer little shaver who earned his livelihood by playing anyone and everyone at so much a game at akl hours of the day and night. One thing that attracted me to the East Side was the fact that most men earned there living in just the same way. Another thing — most of the men were older than I, much older, some of them patriarchs. Still another—they were cultivated. When we weren't playing or talking chess, we talked about music and books: I went to school over there. And I learned philosophy without calling it such. We had no abstract words for what we felt and thought. When we wearied of talk, "Let's have another game—" there was always that. And no one was so hard up that there wasn't someone worse off. I remember the proprietor of a chess cafe who let the addicts sleep on or under tables overnight. I remember a **potzer** too proud for such beds. If he lost instead of won, he'd sleep on park benches. None of us found that out till he died on one. Then we chipped in to save him from Potter's Field. A witty fellow he was; none wittier over there over there where wit is an essential weapon to losers.

I couldn't confirm the date of this publication, but 1930 was indeed the year that volume 20 of the *American Mercury* was published, and I'm inclined to accept the dating of this article as probably accurate. If it is, *patzer/potzer* is at least 29 years older than Ayto gives it credit for being—and the setting of the reported events (Second Avenue on the Upper East Side of Manhattan) and the spelling *potzer* add a bit more support to the notion that *patzer* was derived from a Yiddish word.

Comment: "there is no Yiddish, German, or Hebrew word or word combination to suggest it" - the noun *Patzer*, along with the verb *verpatzen*, are common words in German, denoting a mishap or mistake of some kind that spoils or prevents a success. Whether they are originally loanwords from Yiddish or elsewhere I cannot tell, but [Google NGram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=verpatzt&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cverpatzt%3B%2Cc0) (with the example of the verb's past participle, *verpatzt*) the words existed ...

Comment: ... in German (albeit possibly not as commonly yet) well before the quoted text was written.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Thank you for your comments. I think that Wentworth & Flexner probably took a wrong turn in their brief analysis of the word's origin. Putting forward the English word _patsy_ as the source of _patzen_ is an interesting idea but not very likely to be correct. And their assertion that there is no German or Yiddish word or word combination to suggest _patzen_ seems to be flatly wrong. To me the more contestable question is whether _patzen_ in its current English slang sense originated as _patzen_ (German) or _potzen_ (modified Yiddish) .

Comment: I live in Yorkville, which is traditionally a largely **German** neighborhood on the Upper East Side of Manhattan, although there has certainly been a Yiddish-speaking community here as well. German businesses survive to this day on Second Avenue, including the Heidelberg Restaurant and the Schaller & Weber deli.

Answer (score 2):

"Is [patzer] ever used in a non-chess context?" seemed at first to be a very low bar to clear; that appearance was soon belied by the search. Discounting surnames for the moment (although I will of necessity return to them when providing an origin story), and cleaving to the spirit of the challenge by ruling out game and sport contexts, a use or two in non-game and non-sport contexts did eventually appear; these cleared the "ever" bar, but barely.

[*OED*](http://oed.com/) is content to provide two forms: 'patzer' and 'potzer', both attested from the 1900s. The former, 'patzer', is attested by quotes from 1972 and 2002; the latter, 'potzer', is attested by quotes from 1948 and 1962.

For "ever" use of 'potzer', I uncovered a pun in [*The Age* (Melbourne, Australia; paywalled) of 17 Jul 1997](https://www.newspapers.com/image/123049154/?terms=%22potzer%22), in an article titled "Goat man and other mysterio catastrophes":

> And even if you don't understand a thing on the menu like the lemon couscous or the Mediterranean aioli crouton or the haloumi, don't worry, no one else does either.
>    The secret is to order anything that starts with a P: polenta, pancetta, pecorino or pasta in pineapple chutney, don't ask, just eat, you **potz-er**.

The other secret known to this reporter, but not shared explicitly, is that it doesn't matter if you don't mean a word of the article you're writing.

A second "ever" use of 'potzer' was this, pried from the [COHA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/x4.asp?t=780051&ID=527298283) corpus:

> He was also prone to migraine headaches, and in the last couple of years, that **potzer** Rogan next door had taken to calling him "Morris the Cat." Morris had wondered aloud to Lydia, his second wife, how Rogan would like it if Morris took up calling him "Rogan the hemorrhoid."
>
> *Different Seasons*, Stephen King, 1982.

For 'patzer', this appeared:

> Why am I left slaying my very own soul when my setup is lost in his rosy, bedded eye, his hidden, preying eye gladly digesting my 8:16 innocence? This time the **patzer** must be of the lowest rank, and his foot must be in his toss. His best cast were three sixes, his worst, Canis.
>
> [*Occultus Liber*, Neil Baker, 2014](https://books.google.com/books?id=VNKYAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA8&dq=%22patzer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzz_nSsrLUAhUEyoMKHWt4BGEQ6AEI1wMwTw#v=onepage&q=%22patzer%22&f=false).

It's difficult to say exactly what the context of the appearance on page 8 of the 914 pages of *Occultus Liber* is, but it doesn't seem to be chess, sports, or games, unless "rank" is to be interpreted as an obscure reference to chess or another game.

---

Returning to surnames, and particularly the surname 'Patzer', there are many instances throughout the texts I examined. Almost all of those instances would rightly be said to be in a "non-chess context", but a humorous 1893 name, used in a chess context, may explain the later adoption and use of 'patzer', from "German (colloquial) *Patzer* inveterate bungler (19th cent.) < *patzen* to bungle (19th cent.; probably < German regional (Austria)*Patzen blot*, of uncertain origin) + *-er*" (*OED*).

The year before the German player Emanuel Lasker took the World Chess Champion title (a title he then held for the next 27 years), he played in an international tournament at the Manhattan Chess Club, winning all 13 games. As reported, he did not play at the Club before the tournament, as was usual for the foreign players:

> Lasker, on the other hand, never touched a piece at the Club, but took plenty of exercise in the park. The Anglo-German champion believes in bodily training, and is of opinion that it is time enough for playing chess when the bell rings for the commencement of the tournament.
>    Wednesday evening [the tournament began on Saturday], however, Lasker made an exception and went to "Die Freundschaft" [a New York German social club], where he had to play a game. There is a story of this game which is as interesting as it is new to the great bulk of chess-players.
>    A member of the club, who, in the **German chess parlance**, would be called **E. I. N. Patzer**, was bold enough to say at the club last Winter that Lasker could not give him the odds of a rook and move, and backed his boast by a bet of $50. The bet was taken, but the game could not be played last season because of Lasker's departure for Havana.
>    Wednesday Lasker was asked to comodate [sic] Mr. Patzer, and there was a big crowd of players at the "Freunschaft" when the latter opened the game, Lasker adopting a Sicilian defence. The game and the $50 were won by Lasker after twenty moves.
>
> [*The Evening World* (New York, New York), 30 Sep 1893](https://www.newspapers.com/image/79023998/?terms=%22patzer%22) (paywalled).
>
> [image: E. Lasker, 1893][image: chess game, Lasker Vs. Patzer, 1893]

The "German parlance" mentioned, "E. I. N. Patzer", translates as "one [ein] inveterate bungler", and it is likely this early patzer who supplied the noun for later use by English-speaking chess players.

Comment: Regarding _Occultus Liber_, the sentences following "patzer" refer to "cast", "three sixes", "Canis", "Venus" (all suggesting a [dice game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_Throw), possibly referring to the dice mentioned a few sentences previously); then it talks of "ranks and files", which is suggestive of a chessboard, and "thirty three shadows" might be those of 32 chess pieces plus whatever "'sus" refers to. To the extent that it's possible to make any sense out of the text at all, I don't think we can rule out chess and other games here.

Answer (score 1):

The [Etymological *Duden*](https://archive.org/details/dudenetymologieh0000unse) (an authoritative German dictionary) suggests that *Patzer* has been in use since at least the 19th century, and that the word derives from a dialect expression for "stain":

[image: 1963 Duden definition of "patzen/Patzer"]

> **patzen** (colloquial): "to work shoddily, superficially; to play badly on a musical instrument": This verb, in use since the 19th century, probably belongs to the dialect noun *Patzen* (masculine) "Stain, dirt patch" and therefore actually means "blot, muddle". In addition to the plain verb, the prefix *verpatzen* coll. for "spoil" is in use. Derivation: *Patzer* masc. coll. for "[small] error, mistake; person who works or plays shoddily or badly" (19. Century).

Comment: Thanks, microtherion, but only etymologies starting at the entry into the English lexicon are valid on ELU.

Comment: Since there were some questions whether "Patzer" even has a German origin in the first place, I thought it was important to document the fact that it does. But if that is against policy, I can, of course, delete my post.

Comment: It would be a good answer over on Linguistics. I can't see it opening the floodgates to a lot of non-English discussions here, especially with my flagging.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to comment on potential Yiddish sources of this word, although obviously a more straightforward etymology is strictly by way of German "patzen," to bungle. ("Patzer" may have nonetheless entered chess lexicon through one of the more germanized Yiddish dialects, since after all it is Jews, not Germans, who play chess [with apologies to Magnus Carlssen].) 
In Yiddish there are:

- potshontek plural potshontkes, gender m, beginning, start (source [here](https://www.cs.uky.edu/~raphael/yiddish/dictionary.cgi))
- patshken [image: Patshken] (source [here](http://verterbukh.org/vb))
- and finally, pots [image: Pots] (ibid.)

"Patzer" is however not a Yiddish word in current use, from my own moderately-informed assessment.

Answer (score 0):

*Patzer* has been generalized to mean someone who is an incompetent, an amateur, or a know-nothing in a field or endeavor **other than** chess/checkers or other games:

> After the release of *Dr. Strangelove* an interviewer told Kubrick
> that some viewers felt that he "seemed curiously aloof and detached
> and unmoved by the annihilation of mankind." Kubrick strongly
> disagreed, replying "that the only immorality is that which endangers
> the species; and the only absolute evil, that which threatens
> annihilation." Kubrick, in his films, does not want the **patzers** to
> win. [Elsa Colombani; *A Critical Companion to Stanley Kubrick*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Critical_Companion_to_Stanley_Kubrick/32QGEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22A%20patzer%22&pg=PA133&printsec=frontcover)
> (2020)

> "Okay, Jeremy Granger, a.k.a. King Maybe, producer and studio exec.
> Started out as a ***patzer***, you know, like a personal assistant to
> well-known jerks: agents, third-season TV stars, Brian Sampson."
> Sampson was a producer who was noted for having intentionally backed
> over a meter maid one day when she was writing him a parking ticket an
> he was late for his tennis game. [Timothy Hallinan; *King Maybe*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/King_Maybe/gU4yCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22A%20patzer%22&pg=PT67&printsec=frontcover)
> (2016)

> "All right, Governor Orne's got a problem. He's a decent guy, but if
> you're the governor of West Virginia, you can't just spit in the face
> of Big Coal. On the other hand, he needs to show the state he's not a
> coal company patsy either. He needs a victory where the bad guys are
> really, undeniably shits. But if the feds come in on this, if it's a
> big national story, he's essentially out of the picture. He's got
> political assassinations happening and he can't cope by himself? He
> looks like a **patzer**. [Robert Tanenbaum; *Absolute Rage*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Absolute_Rage/NzmoATTxipsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22A%20patzer%22&pg=PA118&printsec=frontcover) (2002)

UPDATE: **Examples of patzer/potzer prior to 1930, as documented in Sven Yargs's answer**.

> Chess players squeeze out a mite of livelihood,
> squeeze each other for the stake, a nickel a game;
> twelve or thirteen hours buy one's coffee, ones' doughnuts;
> satiety this against the hunger chessdom breeds;
> but—
> you've got to be adroit enough and shrewd enough;
> scholarship won't do; you must have imagination;
> and then you'll need the third and hardest, only age can forge,
> courage to make the move you've felt your brain conceive;
> but—
> if you haven't got the brain to beat him, do it with your tongue;
> scare him from the winning coup, sneak his thought elsewhere:
> call him "**potzer**," "nebich," "kibitz";
> if that trio don't confound him, sneer him "goy"; the weird vernacular
> has always this to addle Jews;
> but — ...
>
> Alfred Kreymborg; [*Blood of Things: A Second Book of Free Forms*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Blood_of_Things/lrIpAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=chess%20potzer&pg=PA122&printsec=frontcover), p.122 (1920)

> "You had a lost game—from the st-start——"
> "What do you know about chess—you *Nebich*——"
> "What do you know—you ***Potzer***——"
>
> Alfred Kreymborg; [*Troubadour: An Autobiography*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Troubadour/m_xaAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=chess%20potzer&pg=PA45&printsec=frontcover), p.45 (1925)