# Yiddish loan words for the foolish & incompetent

Tags: pejorative-language, loanwords, yiddish

Is there a Yiddish loan word to describe someone incompetent or amateurish, or who is a small-time player in a given field of endeavor? The closest I know of are general-purpose insults like `shnook`, `shlemiel`, `schmuck`, &c., &c., but I don't think they have the specific meaning I'm looking for.

Comment: [**Shmegegge**](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EtJD6qvyPyoC&pg=PT444&dq=%22Yiddish+term+for+a+stupid+or+incompetent+person%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Yiddish%20term%20for%20a%20stupid%20or%20incompetent%20person%22&f=false) - *Yiddish term for a stupid or incompetent person.*

Comment: **Klutz** means a physically clumsy person, but the sense is often extended to a bungler in any field of endeavour. However, I've never seen it employed for a small-time player.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Isn't a shmegegge a blowhard---sort of a pompous idiot? I'm thinking more about a video store owner trying to compete with Netflix, or a community theater actor trying to break into Broadway---someone who's in over their head.

Comment: @crmdgn: I just quoted the definition from *Dictionary of Jewish Terms*. There's also ***a message that seems to convey no meaning*** from [memidex](http://www.memidex.com/shmegegge), among others. Words like this often have a broad spread of meanings.

Comment: I would wonder if *schlimazel* might fit. A chronic loser.

Comment: Does it have to be Yiddish? How about "hack"? or suffix -taster

Comment: @crmdgn ...There's this word, of course: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/318545/non-chess-usage-of-patzer

Comment: @anongoodnurse, That's correct.

Comment: In this case, and I say this lightly, a kosher answer is best.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for _schlep_ or _patzer._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned (by usage-N.E. North America) that a **schmendrick** is a young, inexperienced, incompetent, and generally ineffectual but well-meaning person; A "babe in arms" fool; A "Mark" for a professional gambler.

"Oy (Oh, Dear!), the poor schmendrick didn't realize what he was getting into!"

Answer (score 0):

The word Na'ar is used in Yiddish to describe a person who is foolish or unlearned. It is derived from Hebrew were it means a young lad.

Comment: Yiddish, capital y please.

Comment: But has it made it into the English lexicon?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, Not really.

Comment: In that case it's inadmissible as an answer on ELU.

Answer (score -3):

I like **meshuggana** -- it may not convey *exactly* your meaning but it is a lovely, emphatic, almost onomatopoeic word.

From [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/meshuggana):

> A mad or idiotic person.

Also, see the [Wictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mashugana) entry, spelt **mashugana** there.

Comment: _Meshuggane_ specifically means insane.